# Linq To Entities in WebAPI query child entities based on parent fields in the case where URI parameters are optional

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

I have two tables Schedule and ScheduleItems with a one-to-many relationship

Schedule:

- ScheduleID (Guid)
- ChannelID (Guid)
- ScheduleType (string)
- IsComplete (bool)

ScheduleItems:

- ScheduleItemID (Guid)
- ScheduleID (Guid)
- Title (String)
- ScheduledTime (DateTime)
- ContentType (String)

From my webAPI controller for schedule items I would like to return the results of a query based on URL parameters,  I also want the API to be flexible, in that some of the parameters are optional.

So in my ScheduleItems API Controller I thought (dangerous) that I could build up a query depending on which parameters were present in the URI.

My ScheduleItem controller Get action: (What I thought I might be able to do)

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ScheduleItem>> GetScheduleItems()
    {
        var query = _repository.Get(); // returns IQueryable<ScheduleItem>

        query = query.OrderByDescending(si => si.ScheduledTime);

        var parameters = this.ActionContext.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();
        if (parameters != null)
        {
            foreach (var p in parameters)
            {
                if (p.Key.Equals("channelID", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    Guid channelID = Guid.Parse(p.Value);
                    query = query.Where(si => si.Schedule.ChannelID.Equals(channelID));
                }
                if (p.Key.Equals("parentScheduleType", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    query = query.Where(si => si.Schedule.Type.Equals(p.Value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
                }
                if (p.Key.Equals("titleSearchTerm", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    query = query.Where(si => si.Title.Contains(p.Value));
                }
                if (p.Key.Equals("contentType", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    query = query.Where(si => si.ContentType.Equals(p.Value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
                }
                if (p.Key.Equals("isComplete", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    bool isComplete = bool.Parse(p.Value);
                    query = query.Where(si => si.ScheduleMetadata.IsAsRun.Equals(isComplete));
                }
                if (p.Key.Equals("take", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    int count = int.Parse(p.Value);
                    query = query.Take(count);
                }
            }
        }
        var result = await query.ToListAsync();
        return result.AsEnumerable();
    }
```

Though this does return some of the desired results, it does not return the same number of results when compared to running an equivalent SQL query directly on the database.

Clearly I am off track here.

I considered abandoning this and writing a controller action for each of the possible query parameter variation, But when considering this I realised I would be creating a ton of controller actions. I feel there must be a better way to get what I want without writing so many controller actions.

What is the best way of achieving this?

Note: I cannot use OData querying on the controller side as this broke a custom JSon.NET de-serialising on the client side.

Comment: Are you expecting `and` logic or `or` logic? If you are expecting `or` logic, this won't work. If you are expecting `and` logic, then it should. However, `Take` might not be the last action, which could significantly alter expected results in both cases. So if you are in fact expecting `and` logic, then all you need to do is move the `Take` case out of your loop and make sure to do it last.

Comment: Yes!!! Thank you so much, kicking my self for not seeing this.  If you care to make it an answer, Ill mark it up as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are expecting logical *AND* logic, then the idea in general should work. However, `"take"` might not be the last item in `parameters`. When it is not, it could significantly change the expected results, because it might remove items when the result set *at that time* is larger than the amount of items taken.

All you need to do to solve the issue is take the logic for `Take()` out of the loop to make sure it's done last.